# Condition on Compute sum Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex-5.1

Basic Info

```
APEX version 5.1
DB version, edition and host OS 11.2 /SE on Windows 7
Browser(s)/version(s) used 'Fire Fox'
UI/Theme Vista
Templates Hero
Region type Classic Report
```

I have a classic report for departments with average salary column with compute sum = Yes

I have created a checkbox using the following select

```
APEX_ITEM.CHECKBOX(p_idx=>1, p_value=>DEPT_ID)  as select_dept
```

The question is how to make the summation of average salary for the checked departments only as shown in the below figure

[image]

the summary should change while check and uncheck the `select_dept` checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know.

Though, here's another idea: as you want to compute certain values for selected departments, you could create a **Shuttle item**, select those departments and use its value in report's query (note that values will be separated by a colon sign, so you'll have to convert them to rows. There's a technique to do that, you'll find it on the Internet. If you choose to use this suggestion and need assistance, say so).

**Alternatively**, if it is an option for you, switch to an Interactive Report which is much more flexible than the Classic Report. In there, using its <kbd>Actions</kbd> menu, you could use computations or aggregations (both are in the Format menu), as well as filter data.

I understand that this isn't even close to what you want as checkboxes are rather user-friendly in such a case.

**Maybe / probably** it can be done with some additional programming (using JavaScript, jQuery, whatever), but I (unfortunately) wouldn't know how to do that.